# tsk = AsyncMethod vs tsk = Task.Run(AddressOf AsyncMethod) threads behavior difference

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await, task

I'm trying to understand difference in behavior of 2 lines of code those commented as "Case 1" and "Case 2".
Here's the code:

```
'Handler-----------------------------------------------------------------

Private Async Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Await Worker()
End Sub

'Worker------------------------------------------------------------------

Async Function Worker() As Task
    Debug.WriteLine("I am worker just started. Thread is: " & System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)

    'Dim tsk = Task.Run(AddressOf AsyncWork)       'Case 1
    Dim tsk = AsyncWork()                          'Case 2

    Dim b
    For j = 0 To 1000
        For i = 0 To 1000
            If i = 500 And j = 500 Then Debug.WriteLine("I am worker inside my circle. Thread is: " & System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
            b = i * j
        Next
    Next

    Await tsk.ConfigureAwait(False)

    Debug.WriteLine("I am worker after work. Thread is: " & System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)

End Function

'Work------------------------------------------------------------------

Async Function AsyncWork() As Task(Of String)
    Await Task.Delay(1)
    Debug.WriteLine("I am work. Thread is: " & System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
    Dim a
    For j = 0 To 1000
        For i = 0 To 1000
            a = i * j
        Next
    Next
    Return a.ToString
End Function
```

In the "Case 1" `Dim tsk = Task.Run(AddressOf AsyncWork)`
`AsyncWork` method is started on separate thread as expected.

I can't get in mind why in the "Case 2", when I type `Dim tsk = AsyncWork()`, `AsyncWork` method starts executing on the same thread? What is the difference of these two lines of code?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the articles on my [async-await curation](https://curah.microsoft.com/45553/asyncawait-general).

Comment: @Paulo, looks like your resource is an comprehensive async-await knowledge base, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Case 2, you're just calling the function, as you traditionally would. Of course it will run on the same thread - you haven't asked for any different behavior.

`Task.Run()` is what actually starts up a new task, which is most likely to take place on a different thread.